# How to make a .bat that will ask yes or no and if the guy clicks yes it will go to website

Tags: batch-file

Hi same question above How to make a .bat that will ask yes or no and if the guy clicks yes it will go to website. Its really hard for me because I'm just beginning, I tried this on

```
Start www.websitehere.com
```

and save it as .bat , it works but the problem is I want to ask questions first if yes or no if he wants to proceed.

Comment: Please do not ask questions until you try something or research the topic.

Answer (score 5):

Very Easy:

```
choice /c yn /m "Start Website?"
if %errorlevel% equ 1 Start www.websitehere.com
Exit
```

Comment: Please **do not** use taglines.

Answer (score 1):

Batch scripts do not support any mouse interaction, however if a text prompt is fine with you, this will work:

```
choice
if errorlevel 2 end
start www.websitehere.com
```

Comment: Whoops, we added answers at the same time. :)

Comment: @Monacraft Well, technically I answered 4 seconds before you :)